# VB.NET Upload File with hash character

Tags: vb.net, hash, upload, ftp

Uploading files from PC to FTP seems to be easy with .NET.
There are different solutions to achieve this (My.Computer.Network.UploadFile, WebClient or FtpWebRequest), but I've a strange problem:
I've to upload files with a hash-char inside the filename, f.e. NG#A2#C23123#G995323#Z2333.pdf - If i'ld like to upload one of these files .NET cut the filename and only the filename "NG" arrives the ftp server.

How am I able to solve this problem?

Comment: why is this tagged as VB.Net when the answer is clearly C#?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it via google, after trying a different search phrase:

```
  var ftpfullpath := new UriBuilder();
    ftpfullpath.Scheme := 'ftp';
    ftpfullpath.Host := ftphost; //z.B. "ftp.entwickler-ecke.de"
    ftpfullpath.Path := ftpfilepath; //Zielpfad inkl. Dateiname, also z.B. '/foo#bar.txt'

    var ftp := FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath.Uri) as FtpWebRequest;
```